# npx react-native run-ios raises error on module map file

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

This is the error I get when I run `npx react-native run-ios`:

```
fatal error: module map file '/Users/hugovillalobos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cinetogo-diksubmseucchbcogynagkpwyphw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap' not found
```

Everything was fine and running until I installed **redux** y **redux-saga**, and I have no clue what this is about.

**Edit**

This is my `Podfile`:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'cinetogo' do
  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  target 'cinetogoTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'cinetogo-tvOS' do
  # Pods for cinetogo-tvOS

  target 'cinetogo-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

Comment: What extension are you using **. xcodeproj** or **.xcworkspace**?

Comment: @LeriGogsadze I am sorry, I am pretty new on React-Native and I am just following some Udemy curse. Where can I find the information you are asking for?

Comment: Are you familiar with XCode?

Comment: @LeriGogsadze Not really. I can see that inside `Pods` directory is a file named `Pods.xcodeproj` and I don't see a `Pods.xcworkspace`. I don't know if that is relevant for your question.

Comment: Ok, so we can try one solution, remove `Podfile.lock`, and run `pod install` from `ios` directory.

Comment: @LeriGogsadze nothing, just the same

Comment: Then launch XCode, press `command+o`, from dialog window choose your project. In `ios` folder will be `project_name.xcodeproj` and `project_name.xcworkspace` files and choose the second one.

Comment: @LeriGogsadze now I know, I saw this when building `info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace cinetogo.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme cinetogo -destination id=E64657C9-B493-467D-8891-B7B02DFFF9E7")`, so I am using `.xcworkspace`

Comment: One more try. What is the target iOS in your Podfile?

Comment: `platform :ios, 'target_version'`?

Comment: @LeriGogsadze I added my `Podfile` to the question. I don't see that `'target_version'` variable

Comment: Change 10.0 to 9.0, run `pod install` again and check

Comment: I got A LOT of this warnings: `[!] The platform of the target `cinetogoTests` (iOS 9.0) may not be compatible with `glog (0.3.5)` which has a minimum requirement of iOS 10.0 - tvOS 10.0.`

Comment: [There](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28503) are a lot of things and hope one of them will help you.